# how to ImageView work when import DropDown in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu, uikit

I want it to be able to display images and text in the cell when clicking on the button but it doesn't work

```
import UIKit
import DropDown

class MyDropDownCell: DropDownCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}

@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let array = ["uploadvalidation","trashAdd"]
    dropDown.dataSource = ["Download report","Delete"]
    
    dropDown.anchorView = sender
    dropDown.cornerRadius = 20.0
    dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: -140 , y: 26)
    dropDown.backgroundColor = .orange
    dropDown.show()
    dropDown.cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MyDropDownCell", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
    print("Cell created: \(MyDropDownCell.self)")
    dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
        guard let cell = cell as? MyDropDownCell else { return }
        print("Index: \(index), Item: \(item), Image Name: \(array[index])")
        // Setup your custom UI components
        
        
        cell.logoImage.image = UIImage(named: array[index])
    }
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3AP5.png)

I tried everything but it still doesn't work

Comment: `"uploadvalidation","trashAdd"` are you sure this images are in you xcode project. can you add your result screenshot in question.

Comment: Please update your question with a far better description than "doesn't work". In what way exactly doesn't it work?

Answer (score -1):

Try reloading the tableView that you are using MyDropDownCell